# How to restart whole program in C

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to make automatic updates for a program, if the hash online is different from the hash of the current program it executes it, however I'm having issues in that, when I try to stop the old program (kill -9 pid) and start the new one from within the C program, it kills both programs

I tried downloading the new version, using setpid to get a new pid and parsing the pid of the current version as an argument, then using kill -9 to kill the old instance of the program, however when I do this it kills both programs

Comment: Generally you'd just exec the new program to replace the current process image with it.

Comment: So, I tried with execv and it killed both, but if that method doesn't replace image then I can try one of the other execs that does and see if it works

Comment: How are you doing the update? Your original post suggests that you have a separate cron job script that checks for update, downloads a copy, kills the old instance, renames the file, starts new instance. But, Shawn suggested that the program do the download/update itself. So, which are you using (wanting to use)? Note that the program (call it `/path/to/myprogram`), should download the copy to a temp file (e.g. `/path/to/myprogram.TMP`). Then, when complete and verified, do: `rename("/path/to/myprogram.TMP","/path/to/myprogram"); execv();`

Comment: If you create a very simple test-program, like `int main(int argc. char *argv[]) { if (argc > 1 && strcmp(argv[0], "from exec") == 0) { printf("Called from exec\n"); } else { execl(argv{[0], "from exec", NULL); } }`, does that work? Then expand from that.

Comment: Also, don't start the new program, just overwrite the executable program file, and call `exec` in a suitable way. A better way to make sure the old file is removed by the overwrite, is to `fork` a new process, and in the child process do the `exec`, while the parent process calls `exit`.